# Why RecyclerView items is broken when keyboard appears?

Tags: android

I have following structure of layout:

```
NestedScrollView
   ConstrainstsLayout
      SearchView
      RecyclerView
      RecyclerView
```

When I click to `SearchView`, the keyboard appears and the items of bottom `RecyclerView` becomes larger. It is not possible to see items of `RecyclerView` together. They shown only one by one, because of their height, that became larger after showing keyboard. So, how to solve problem? Here is the layout.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="tech.nplus.yaptk.ui.payment.PaymentViewModel" />

</data>


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:queryHint="@string/find_service"

            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/fast_payment_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchView" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/service_list_parent_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:items="@{viewModel.items}"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fast_payment_rv"

            />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Here is the 3 screens. 1 shows before keyboard appearing, 2 shows after(notice that elements disappeared), 3 shows how elements became larger. 
[image] [image] [image]

P.S. I put `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` , otherwise, my `BottomNavigationView` appears above keyboard.

Comment: Post some screenshots

Comment: You can use android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize" in AndroidManifest.xml for your current activity, and use android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in styles or rootLayout.

Comment: @MaxAves Posted some screenshots.

Comment: @Madhur Didn't help. BottomNavigationView appears above keyboard in your solution

Comment: now we do need xml files for sure

Comment: @MaxAves Actually, it was on gist. But I post anyway.